# invoking proc with instance_eval with arguments?

Tags: ruby

I know this works:

```
proc = Proc.new do
  puts self.hi + ' world'
end

class Usa
  def hi
    "Hello!"
  end
end
Usa.new.instance_eval &proc
```

However I want to pass arguments to proc, so I tried this which does not work:

```
proc = Proc.new do |greeting| 
  puts self.hi + greeting
end

class Usa
  def hi
    "Hello!"
  end
end
Usa.new.instance_eval &proc, 'world' # does not work
Usa.new.instance_eval &proc('world') # does not work
```

Can anyone help me make it work?

Comment: You have a typo. `gsub!("gretting", "greeting")`

Comment: fixed now. Sorry about that. Thanks Marc.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use [`instance_exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec) instead of [`instance_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval) when you need to pass arguments.

```
proc = Proc.new do |greeting| 
  puts self.hi + greeting
end

class Usa
  def hi
    "Hello, "
  end
end
Usa.new.instance_exec 'world!', &proc # => "Hello, world!"
```

Note: it's new to Ruby 1.8.7, so upgrade or `require 'backports'` if needed.

Comment: Is there anything `backports` *can't* do? :-)

Comment: @Jörg :-)  I wish there wasn't... Too bad some things are out of reach, like `Method#source_location` or the encoding stuff. And `instance_exec` is the ugliest hack in the gem...